# при верстке нужно такие кружочки

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

[image]

кружочки которые мне нужны.Как оно делается?

Comment: как я понял, это такой слайдер. Тогда вам в помощь [FullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/#page1)

Comment: А визуально как получить это?

Comment: это обычные закругленные дивы

Comment: `div` с `border-radius: 50%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.big {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #00A3FF;
}

.middle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #00A3FF;
}

.small {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #00A3FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big">
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
  </div>
  <div class="small">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавлю.. для того, что бы отрисовать круг, нужно, ширину и высоту установить одним числом (четным), а border-radius всегда должен быть равен половине. Если вам ответ был полезен, то пожалуйста, поставьте галочку.

Comment: о какой галочке речь - ваш ответ не соответствует - кто то ещё плюс поставил

Comment: Как был поставлен вопрос "при верстке нужно такие кружочки
", такой ответ я и дал. Человек просил просто нарисовать "кружочки", и он их получил. Поэтому о каком не соответствии идет речь?

Comment: сейчас всмотрелся еще раз на картинку, и только сейчас увидел "кружочки" слайдера. Картинка темная, сразу не заметишь + солнце в монитор. Поэтому вот такой ответ.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста т.к. я новичок, как поставить их там где мне хочется? с помощю margin?

Comment: смотря где хотите их расположить.

Comment: Скажите, как и где их хотите видеть? Я подскажу.

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.slider {
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.dots.-left,
.dots.-right {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.dots.-top,
.dots.-bottom {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.dots.-left {left: 0;}
.dots.-top {top: 0;}
.dots.-right {right: 0;}
.dots.-bottom {bottom: 0;}

.dot {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #09f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dots.-left .dot:not(:last-child),
.dots.-right .dot:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dots.-top .dot:not(:last-child),
.dots.-bottom .dot:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dot.--active {
  background: #09f;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="dots -left">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot --active"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dots -top">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot --active"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dots -right">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot --active"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dots -bottom">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot --active"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```